# Random Forest in R - many classes

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I want to do a multilabel classification with R randomForest.
I have ten classes A..J,

I found examples how to predict a single class, like:

```
r = randomForest(J ~., data=train, importance=TRUE, do.trace=100)
```

But I want to predict more classes, for instance H,I,J. (i.e. say that only A..G are given attributes).
How can I do it?

I have an idea of preserving A..G and only one of the predicted classes (H/I/J) and run randomForest 3 times, but maybe there is a better way? To do it in one run?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question could be a lot clearer. Are you saying you want to be able to predict classes that don't exist in your training data? Because that will be....difficult.

Comment: No, I mean I want to treat 7 columns as given and predict values of other 3 columns.

Comment: I'm not aware of a multivariate RF package (could be wrong though...). Easy thing would be to fit three models.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that all attributes H, I and J are binary. Then you can just predict a new attribute K with 2^3 possible values and then decode the result back into 3 attributes:

- 1 -> 0,0,0
- 2 -> 0,0,1
- 3 -> 0,1,0
- 4 -> 0,1,1
- 5 -> 1,0,0
- 6 -> 1,0,1
- 7 -> 1,1,0
- 8 -> 1,1,1